# Why does Vite not resolve my alias for a rest API URL?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vite

I added a `server.proxy` in my `vite.config.js` and added the path to `resolv.alias` but if I try to use `@api` in my Vue components the app tries to call `http://localhost:5173/@api/login`.

Here's my `vite.config.js`:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url';
import { resolve, dirname } from 'node:path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import VueI18nPlugin from '@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n/vite';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    proxy: {
      // Development API proxy
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://apiUrlForDevelopment',
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    VueI18nPlugin({
      include: resolve(dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)), './src/locales/**'),
      strictMessage: false,
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
      '@api': '/api',
    },
  },
  build: {
    // Production API URL
    define: {
      'process.env.API_URL': 'http://apiUrlForProduction', 
    },
  },
});
```

This is how I try to use the `@api` in one of my components:

```
let login = () => {
  axios.post('@api/login', {...})
  .then((resp) => {...})
  .catch((err) => console.log("Login failed:", err))}
```

I tried to use different chars instead of `@`, e.g. `§` or `~`,
I also tried to use my Vite config without the simple `@` but I can't find a solution.

Comment: Because resolving modules (for import etc.) and making Axios requests are two completely different things? Just make your requests to the relative path, `/api/login`, so they hit the proxy and get sent to the configured target.